# c++11 Singleton is creating new instances

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my singleton

```
class MySingleton {
private:
    int myNumber;
public:
    static MySingleton &get() {
        static MySingleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    int getMyNumber() const {
        return myNumber;
    }

    void setMyNumber(int myNumber) {
        MySingleton::myNumber = myNumber;
    }
};
```

and this is the code to test it

```
MySingleton t1 = MySingleton::get();
t1.setMyNumber(6);
printf("t1: %d \n", t1.getMyNumber());

MySingleton t2 = MySingleton::get();
printf("t2: %d \n", t2.getMyNumber());
```

Now the output I get is

```
t1: 6 
t2: 0
```

but te expected result would be

```
t1: 6 
t2: 6
```

It looks like `MySingleton::get()` is creating a new instance, something it shouldn't do of course.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? You didn't forbid copying or assignment. The compiler has no way to decipher you want a singleton concept, you have to specify that behavior.

Comment: Do note that your singleton is not a singleton.  As is it can be default constructed and copied.

Comment: when you call `setMyNumber(6)` you call it on a copy (named `t1`) of the singleton. The next call to `get` returns a reference to the same instance as before, just that it has no idea about the changes you made to the copy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `get()` isn't creating the copy. The assignment to `t1` and `t2` is doing it. To avoid it change those to references: `MySingleton& t1 = MySingleton::get()`.

And in order to avoid accidental errors remove the copy and assignment operators:

```
MySingleton(const MySingleton& other) = delete;
MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton& other) = delete;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you create a copy of the instance in these lines:

```
MySingleton t1 = MySingleton::get();
MySingleton t2 = MySingleton::get();
```

and change the copy.

To make it work you have to add a reference:

```
MySingleton& t1 = MySingleton::get();
MySingleton& t2 = MySingleton::get();
```

Also note, that the classic singleton design assumes deleted copy constructor and copy assignment operator to avoid such bugs:

```
class MySingleton {
    private:
        // ...
    public:
        // ...
        MySingleton(const MySingleton&) = delete;
        void operator=(const MySingleton&) = delete;
};
```

---

P.S. You might find [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern?rq=1) useful. It shows the implementation details of a singleton pattern with *C++*.

Comment: Therefore needs to define a (`private`) constructor. `MySingleton():myNumber(0){};` maybe?

Comment: @Persixty I've provided OP with a part of implementation which was relative to his problem. He might easily found the full implementation, so I've decided not to post it. And yes, constructor should be private, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the singleton instead of obtaining a reference:

```
MySingleton &t1 = MySingleton::get();
```

Mark the copy- an move-assignment and -constructors as delete and make the constructor and destructor private:

```
class MySingleton
{
public:
    MySingleton(const MySingleton&) = delete;
    void operator=(const MySingleton&) = delete;

    MySingleton(MySingleton&&) = delete;
    void operator=(MySingleton&&) = delete;

private:
    MySingleton() = default;
    ~MySingleton() = default;

};
```

Note that you probably just want a global variable instead of a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You declare both t1 and t2 as instances of the class rather than references to the class.

The get function is implemented correctly but then each instance is constructed upon assignment.
Note that making your constructor private would have prevented this bug at compilation.

I suggest going through a tutorial on how to implement Singletons in c++ to learn some good practices, or simply using an existing well-made impelmentation.